# Pyspark sum of columns after union of dataframe

Tags: dataframe, apache-spark, pyspark, apache-spark-sql

How can I sum all columns after unioning two dataframe ?

I have this first df with one row per user:

```
df = sqlContext.createDataFrame([("2022-01-10", 3, 2,"a"),("2022-01-10",3,4,"b"),("2022-01-10", 1,3,"c")], ["date", "value1", "value2", "userid"])
df.show()

+----------+------+------+------+
|      date|value1|value2|userid|
+----------+------+------+------+
|2022-01-10|     3|     2|     a|
|2022-01-10|     3|     4|     b|
|2022-01-10|     1|     3|     c|
+----------+------+------+------+
```

date value will always be the today's date.

and I have another df, with multiple row per userid this time, so one value for each day:

```
df2 = sqlContext.createDataFrame([("2022-01-01", 13, 12,"a"),("2022-01-02",13,14,"b"),("2022-01-03", 11,13,"c"),
                                 ("2022-01-04", 3, 2,"a"),("2022-01-05",3,4,"b"),("2022-01-06", 1,3,"c"),
                                 ("2022-01-10", 31, 21,"a"),("2022-01-07",31,41,"b"),("2022-01-09", 11,31,"c")], ["date", "value3", "value4", "userid"])
df2.show()

+----------+------+------+------+
|      date|value3|value4|userid|
+----------+------+------+------+
|2022-01-01|    13|    12|     a|
|2022-01-02|    13|    14|     b|
|2022-01-03|    11|    13|     c|
|2022-01-04|     3|     2|     a|
|2022-01-05|     3|     4|     b|
|2022-01-06|     1|     3|     c|
|2022-01-10|    31|    21|     a|
|2022-01-07|    31|    41|     b|
|2022-01-09|    11|    31|     c|
+----------+------+------+------+
```

After unioning the two of them with this function, here what I have:

```
def union_different_tables(df1, df2):
    columns_df1 = df1.columns
    columns_df2 = df2.columns
    data_types_df1 = [i.dataType for i in df1.schema.fields]
    data_types_df2 = [i.dataType for i in df2.schema.fields]
    
    for col, _type in zip(columns_df1, data_types_df1):
        if col not in df2.columns:
            df2 = df2.withColumn(col, f.lit(None).cast(_type))
    for col, _type in zip(columns_df2, data_types_df2):
        if col not in df1.columns:
            df1 = df1.withColumn(col, f.lit(None).cast(_type))
    union = df1.unionByName(df2)
    return union

+----------+------+------+------+------+------+
|      date|value1|value2|userid|value3|value4|
+----------+------+------+------+------+------+
|2022-01-10|     3|     2|     a|  null|  null|
|2022-01-10|     3|     4|     b|  null|  null|
|2022-01-10|     1|     3|     c|  null|  null|
|2022-01-01|  null|  null|     a|    13|    12|
|2022-01-02|  null|  null|     b|    13|    14|
|2022-01-03|  null|  null|     c|    11|    13|
|2022-01-04|  null|  null|     a|     3|     2|
|2022-01-05|  null|  null|     b|     3|     4|
|2022-01-06|  null|  null|     c|     1|     3|
|2022-01-10|  null|  null|     a|    31|    21|
|2022-01-07|  null|  null|     b|    31|    41|
|2022-01-09|  null|  null|     c|    11|    31|
+----------+------+------+------+------+------+
```

What I want to get is the sum of all columns in `df2` (I have 10 of them in the real case) till the date of the day for each `userid`, so one row per user:

```
 +----------+------+------+------+------+------+
|      date|value1|value2|userid|value3|value4|
+----------+------+------+------+------+------+
|2022-01-10|     3|     2|     a|  47  |  35  |
|2022-01-10|     3|     4|     b|  47  |  59  |
|2022-01-10|     1|     3|     c|  23  |  47  |
+----------+------+------+------+------+------+
```

Since I have to do this operation for multiple tables, here what I tried:

```
user_window = Window.partitionBy(['userid']).orderBy('date')
    
list_tables = [df2]

list_col_original = df.columns

for table in list_tables:
    df = union_different_tables(df, table)
    list_column = list(set(table.columns) - set(list_col_original))

    list_col_original.extend(list_column)

    df = df.select('userid',
            *[f.sum(f.col(col_name)).over(user_window).alias(col_name) for col_name in list_column])
df.show()

+------+------+------+
|userid|value4|value3|
+------+------+------+
|     c|    13|    11|
|     c|    16|    12|
|     c|    47|    23|
|     c|    47|    23|
|     b|    14|    13|
|     b|    18|    16|
|     b|    59|    47|
|     b|    59|    47|
|     a|    12|    13|
|     a|    14|    16|
|     a|    35|    47|
|     a|    35|    47|
+------+------+------+
```

But that give me a sort of cumulative sum, plus I didn't find a way to add all the columns in the resulting df.

The only thing is that I can't do any join ! My df are very very large and any join is taking too long to compute.

Do you know how I can fix my code to have the result I want ?

Comment: what version of spark are you on

Comment: I am using spark 3.0.2 :)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

After union of `df1` and `df2`, you can group by `userid` and sum all columns except `date` for which you get the max.

Note that for the union part, you can actually use [`DataFrame.unionByName`](https://spark.apache.org/docs/latest/api/python/reference/api/pyspark.sql.DataFrame.unionByName.html) if you have the same data types but only number of columns can differ:

```
df = df1.unionByName(df2, allowMissingColumns=True)
```

Then group by and agg:

```
import pyspark.sql.functions as F

result = df.groupBy("userid").agg(
    F.max("date").alias("date"),
    *[F.sum(c).alias(c) for c in df.columns if c not in ("date", "userid")]
)

result.show()

#+------+----------+------+------+------+------+
#|userid|      date|value1|value2|value3|value4|
#+------+----------+------+------+------+------+
#|     a|2022-01-10|     3|     2|    47|    35|
#|     b|2022-01-10|     3|     4|    47|    59|
#|     c|2022-01-10|     1|     3|    23|    47|
#+------+----------+------+------+------+------+
```

This supposes the second dataframe contains only dates prior to the today date in the first one. Otherwise, you'll need to filter `df2` before union.

Comment: it's perfect, thanks a lot! the unionByName din't work even if I am using spark 3.0.2 I don't understand why that's why I used this function.